# Websphere not starting up. Can't recognize debug port

Tags: java, websphere

While trying to start up websphere 8 on RAD 8 (on a win 7 machine) it spits out this error

```
Failure to identify the server debug port number while parsing the server.xml file at D:/IBM/RAD85/WebSphere80/AppServer/profiles/CWB_66/config/cells/9GQ29432Node04Cell/nodes/9GQ29432Node03/servers/server1/server.xml.
```

Below is the configuration of the jvm entry tag

```
  <processDefinitions executableTarget="com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer" executableTargetKind="JAVA_CLASS" workingDirectory="${USER_INSTALL_ROOT}" xmi:id="JavaProcessDef_1183122130078" xmi:type="processexec:JavaProcessDef">
<execution processPriority="20" runAsGroup="" runAsUser="" xmi:id="ProcessExecution_1183122130078"/>
<ioRedirect stderrFilename="${SERVER_LOG_ROOT}/native_stderr.log" stdoutFilename="${SERVER_LOG_ROOT}/native_stdout.log" xmi:id="OutputRedirect_1183122130078"/>
<monitoringPolicy autoRestart="true" maximumStartupAttempts="3" nodeRestartState="STOPPED" pingInterval="60" pingTimeout="300" xmi:id="MonitoringPolicy_1183122130078"/>
<jvmEntries debugArgs="-Dcom.ibm.ws.classloader.j9enabled=true -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=7780" debugMode="true" genericJvmArguments="-Xquickstart" hprofArguments="" runHProf="false" verboseModeClass="false" verboseModeGarbageCollection="false" verboseModeJNI="false" xmi:id="JavaVirtualMachine_1183122130078">
  <systemProperties name="com.ibm.security.jgss.debug" required="false" value="off" xmi:id="Property_1"/>
  <systemProperties name="com.ibm.security.krb5.Krb5Debug" required="false" value="off" xmi:id="Property_2"/>
  <systemProperties name="7m00_SF_TEST_USER_ID" required="false" value="529472540" xmi:id="Property_1338195717501"/>
  <systemProperties name="com.ibm.ws.management.event.pull_notification_timeout" required="false" value="120000" xmi:id="Property_9999999999999"/>
</jvmEntries>
```

I'm not really sure why 7780 is not being recognized. There is no other java process running in the task manager. Can somebody please help me figure out what needs to be changed? Is there more info you might need?

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. Were you able to find a solution?